# What happens when Amazon S3 deletion is in progress and upload is trying to overwrite same object in same bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

We have a CICD pipeline which deletes and then uploads to S3 for the same file. We are deleting all files in directory first and then upload files because there might be unwanted files left which needs to be removed in the directory if we just do the upload files which would do the overwrite. What would happen if there is S3 delete in progress and meanwhile upload is requested to overwrite it? Will this file be deleted in the end or left with overwritten file?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Amazon S3 data consistency model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html) where it says that it offers read-after-write consistency after PUTS of new objects. And eventual consistency for OVERWRITE PUTS and DELETES.

Amazon S3 does not currently support object locking. If two PUT requests are simultaneously made to the same key, the request with the latest time stamp wins. If this is an issue, you will need to build an object-locking mechanism into your application.

So in your case you can run into this undesired scenario where your object winds up deleted: if the new PUT goes through before the DELETE executes, than it will be seen as an UPDATE instead of a brand new put. In this case the DELETE might execute AFTER that second PUT resulting in no object available at all.

Comment: So if PUT goes through after DELETE is executed then will the object still be available? 
Also I am bit confused on "it will be seen as an UPDATE instead of a brand new put.". So  is PUT and UPDATE different?